# Reshape matrix before matrix multiplication

Tags: python, performance, pytorch, matrix-multiplication, transformer-model

I have a snippet of the `forward` step of "Transformer Neural Network" using Pytorch.

- Source: https://github.com/pbloem/former/blob/master/former/transformers.py
- Simplified to below code by me.

With:

- `b: batch_size`, `t: input sequence length`, `k: embedding length`, `self.num_vocabs: output classes`
- `self.toprobs(x)`: a `nn.Linear` layer with in/output features `(k, num_vocabs)`.

```
    def forward(self, x):
        tokens = self.token_embedding(x)
        b, t, k = tokens.size()

        x = self.transformer_block(tokens)

        x = x.view(b * t, k)
        x = self.toprobs(x)
        x = x.view(b, t, self.num_vocabs)

        output = F.log_softmax(x, dim=2)

        return output
```

Given: `b = 2, t = 2, k = 3, self.num_vocabs = 256`.

- The output shape of `x` after `x = self.transformer_block(tokens)` is `(2, 2, 3)`.
- Reshape `x` to `(b * t, k) -> (4, 3)`, then pass throught `self.toprobs(x)` I got `(4, 256)`, then reshape again back to `(2, 2, 256)`.

Question:

- Why `x` need to reshape to `(b * t, k)`? If I keep `x` shape at `(2, 2, 3)` and pass throght `self.toprobs(x)`, I stil have the same results and shape `(2, 2, 256)`.
- Is there any beneficial in accelerate or memory usage of matrix multiplication step?

```
    def forward(self, x):
        tokens = self.token_embedding(x)
        b, t, k = tokens.size()

        x = self.transformer_block(tokens)

        # Same result without matrix reshape
        x = self.toprobs(x)

        output = F.log_softmax(x, dim=2)

        return output
```

Comment: "from Transformer in Pytorch" is this a specific implementation you found somewhere? It doesn't seem to be from https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/transformer.html#Transformer
"Why do we need to reshape" are you asking *if* or "why" you need to?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just one particular person's implementation decision. Maybe they felt that it was easier to think about the dimensions this way, since they may feel that it's more explicit about what specific dimension is being transformed. Personally, I'd probably prefer not to change the batch dimension.

View doesn't actually change the underlying data on the tensor (a view of a tensor shares the same storage). The behavior of [nn.Linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) is only based on the final dimension, which isn't being changed in the view operation in your code snippet (`H` in the linked doc). Based on the docs, I doubt there's any performance difference, and it makes sense to me that you'd see the same results either way.